# How to get size of bitmapdata converted into bytearray

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, bitmapdata

I have bitmapdata object converted to bytearray:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = bitmapDataA.getPixels(bitmapDataA.rect);
```

and I save it as .jpg file for later:

```
writeStream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.bytesAvailable);
```

Now, when I want to retrieve the data:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("data/"+photoNameVec[loadCounter]);         
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var fileContent:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
fileStream.readBytes(fileContent);
fileStream.close();         
var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(XXX, YYY);
bmpData.setPixels(bmpData.rect, fileContent);
addChild(new Bitmap(bmpData));
```

But I need to get exact XXX and YYY to show the graphics correctly. How can I do this?

EDIT:

As there was no way to determine bitmapdata width and height based on bytearray, I decided to transform all pictures I take to 1024px x 768px:

```
var bitmapDataA:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mpLoaderInfo.width, mpLoaderInfo.height);
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale( 1024 / mpLoaderInfo.width, 768 / mpLoaderInfo.height);
var bitmapDataB:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1024,768);
bitmapDataB.draw(mpLoaderInfo.content, matrix, null, null, new Rectangle(0,0,1024,768), true);
```

*Still waiting for tips on getting Width x Height from bytearray created by **getPixels** method of bitmapdata.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's the most suiting solution :)
Simply expand the the bytearray with extra values from which I shall gather width and height.

http://www.ghostwire.com/blog/archives/as3-serializing-bitmaps-storing-bitmapdata-as-raw-binarybytearray/

Ps.: Creating and reading uncompressed files is way faster than making png/jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Loader` class to load the image then you can access it's `width/height` and `BitmapData`

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("data/"+photoNameVec[loadCounter]);
var myImage:BitmapData;

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(file.url);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
loader.load(urlReq);

function loaded(e:Event):void
{
    var bmp:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
    myImage = bmp.bitmapData;
    trace(myImage.width, myImage.height);
}
```

And here is with `loadBytes`

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, loaded);
loader.loadBytes(yourByteArray);

function loaded(e:Event):void
{
    var bmp:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
    myImage = bmp.bitmapData;
    trace(myImage.width, myImage.height);
}
```

Comment: My file is not encoded as jpg, it only contains raw bitmapdata bytearray. So loaded file doesnt provide a bitmap in it's content :(

Comment: Mayby there is a way to transform the bytearray into a bytearray of desired size? I heard about bytearrays transformations somewhere, but dont know how to use it

Comment: You can use this http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes() to load your byte array into the `Loader`

Comment: The thing is myPhoto001.jpg file is not a .jpg file it only has .jpg format letters but it contains raw bitmapdata converted to bytearray. I dont want it to be .jpg to prevent quality loss. Is it possible to simply get width and height of bytes when bytes = bitmapDataA.getPixels(bitmapDataA.rect), with no access to bitmapDataA ?

Comment: Once you convert it to an array of bytes there is no way to know its dimensions from just the bytearray. That information is stored in the file format along with the image data. If you don't want to lose quality just save as png.

Answer (score 0):

The byte array created by getPixels does not contain any information on the height or width of the bitmap, it's simply an "unsigned integer (a 32-bit unmultiplied pixel value) for each pixel".

So you'll need to either write it as an image format (PNG/JPG) which will require encoding (hence time), or simply add the width and height to your byte array before writing to file.

Eg in your stream writer:

```
writeStream.writeInt( bitmapDataA.width );
writeStream.writeInt( bitmapDataA.height );
writeStream.writeBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.bytesAvailable);
```

Then when you are loading:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("data/"+photoNameVec[loadCounter]);         
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

var w:int = fileStream.readInt();
var h:int = fileStream.readInt();

var fileContent:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
fileStream.readBytes(fileContent);
fileStream.close();         

var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData( w , h);

bmpData.setPixels(bmpData.rect, fileContent);
addChild(new Bitmap(bmpData));
```